# Python json schema get property parameters based on path

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am using Python [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) package for JSON config file validation. Everything works perfectly. But now I want to read the property parameters (for example `title`, `description`, `minimum` ...) for specific property path.

For example, I have the schema:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "group1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "prop1": {
          type: "number",
          minimum: 1000,
          maximum: 2000
        },
        "prop2": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "number",
    "maximum": 12345,
    "description": "This is an aditional property."
  }
}
```

And I want to get the minimum value of `prop1`, something like:

```py
val = schema["group1"]["prop1"]["minimum"]
val = schema["group1/prop1/minimum"]
val = get_schema_param(schema, ["group1", "prop1", "minimum"])
# etc.
```

Or some adiotional property:

```py
val = schema["groupXYZ"]["description"] # "This is an aditional property."
# etc.
```

I know that I can access it like `schema["properties"]["group1"]["properties"]["prop1"]["minimum"]` but this is easy only for simple schemas, without `additionalProperties`, `patternProperties`, `anyOff` etc.

Is a standard way for this problem? Can jsonschema package handle this? Or do I have to do it manually?

Thank you.

Comment: are you asking, what's like the normal way of extracting values from a json?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to extract values from JSON file (or python dictionary) that is formatted as **JSON schema** in some clever way (see the last example with `groupXYZ`).

Comment: If you are looking for a json dsl to query data, try https://jmespath.org/

Comment: This JavaScript library does mostly what you're asking for, https://github.com/hyperjump-io/json-schema#annotations-experimental. I don't think there's any similar libraries in any language that provide that kind of functionality.

Comment: Thank you all, but the results is that there is no Python implementation of this functionality. In the end, I iterate over nested JSON schema dictionary and check for `properties` and `items`. It is far from ideal (no `anyOff`, `patterProperties` etc. support), but it meets my needs.